# Storing SQL metadata

Tags: sql, sqlite, metadata

I have a generated SQL table which fits nicely in rows/columns, but I'd also like to store some information about that table such as:

- *When was it generated?*
- *Who generated it?*
- *What script was run to generate it?*
- *Where did the data come from?*
- *A list of key-pair values which didn't fit in the table and really only describe more information about the source*

I'm a little new to SQL, but how would one normally store this information?

I would image that after I `CREATE TABLE foo`, I would need to then `CREATE TABLE foo_meta`, then each question will be a column and I'll need to `INSERT` just one row: the answers to those questions.  Is that a normal way to handle this?

Some clarifications,

- I'm using SQLite3
- Each table represents recorded time-history data where each column is a parameter and each row is a time-step.
- Each table will have associated metadata
- The meta-data contains things like initial conditions and other conditions which weren't recorded in the time-history.
- I will add a bunch of test-results to the same database.  Each test will have a data table (time-history) and a meta-data table.

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Comment: Are you planning on creating a meta-table for each table in a database? If this was just for the purpose of documenting your tables, either create one meta-table for all your tables, or better still re-think how you are doing to document this. Based on the information you want to gather, why not just a document?

Comment: `comment on table foo is 'Created by Arthur Dent at 2018-07-19 15:34 through deployment script';`

Comment: Clarifications added in the original description.